# RDP connection times out before 2-phase authentication completed

Tags: rdp, remmina

We have a connection to a customer site that requires (phone-back) 2-phase authentication.

If I am slow to complete the authentication, Remmina times out with a "Cannot connect to RDP server" error. However, if I'm quick enough (less than about 15 seconds) the connection goes through fine.

Usually, if I re-connect when I get the failure, it goes straight through, as I'm already authenticated.

Wondering if anyone knows where this RDP timeout is defined, and can it be increased?

Comment: According to the manuial, this is in the 'Advanced' tab of the RDP connection profile (https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging)

Comment: Well, in the version I'm running (1.4.2) there is no timeout value in the Advanced tab, and, if the default is 900ms (as your link states) then it can't be that timeout, as mine times out at about 15 seconds, not 900ms.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

Since posting I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and this problem has gone away.